# Get all webpart properties via PowerShell for each page on a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2007

I have a site in SharePoint 2007 (not mine personally) with some subsites. For each subsite, and each of its pages, how can I get all the webpart's properties?

This is using PowerShell (the server does not have Visual Studio, another matter).

Comment: is this a WCM site? a Publishing Web? e.g. pages are in the Pages/ list? Also, what version powershell 1.0 or 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to do some batch programing, iterate sites, pages ... but maybe you can find solution on these links:

[Automating SharePoint 2007 Configurations via STSADM and PowerShell](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/08/stsadm-commands_09.html)
[Enumerate Page Web Parts](http://stsadm.blogspot.com/2007/10/enumerate-page-web-parts.html)

You can also write program on another machine using C# and just execute it on SharePoint server.