# Use PowerShell to Compare SharePoint User Meta Data in User Profile and User Information List

Tags: sharepoint, powershell, sharepoint-2007, powershell-2.0

I came across a request on [LinkedIn](http://www.linkedin.com/groupAnswers?viewQuestionAndAnswers=&discussionID=12979637&gid=38260&goback=.anh_38260.and_38260_12979637_*2_1.amf_38260_43179148&trk=NUS_DISC_Q-ttle) for a PowerShell script that was required to:

- Retrieve all users from the given SharePoint site-collection
- For each user, the script must retrieve the properties are common between "User Profile" and "User Information List"
- If any of the common fields between the two are different, the user name should be outputted, along with the property name and value of the mismatched data.

I though I would post the question to see if anyone could give pointers on the required script.

Thanks, MagicAndi.

Comment: Just to note, I'm posting this question here, as I intend to answer it myself at some point as a learning exercise. Given that I'm spending (wasting?) my free time looking at another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2075619/get-all-webpart-properties-via-powershell-for-each-page-in-sharepoint-site), that could be some time...

Answer (score 1):

Check the script I have here which gets all user profile properties - I'm not quite there, but perhaps it will help:

[Accessing Sharepoint UserProfile Properties with Powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157038/accessing-sharepoint-userprofile-properties-with-powershell-script)

Comment: Thanks, dunxd, I'll take a look at the script.