# Accessing Sharepoint UserProfile Properties with Powershell script

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

The following script spits out all UserProfile properties for users on Sharepoint 2007:

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles")
# Function:          Get-UserProfiles
# Description:       return a UserProfileManager object containing all user profiles
# Parameters:        SSPName          SSPName    
#
Function global:Get-UserProfiles($SSPName)
{
    $ServerContext = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($SSPName);
    $UPManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServerContext);
    return $UPManager.GetEnumerator();
}

$profiles = Get-UserProfiles("SharedServices");
$profiles | ForEach-Object { $_.GetEnumerator();}
```

However, what I want to do is be able to return a table, or csv file of specific values in the profile, e.g. Username, WorkEmail, WorkPhone.  I have tried piping the output to `|ft Username, WorkEmail, Workphone` and `| select Username, WorkEmail, WorkPhone` but this just returns blanks.

I feel like I am so close.  I don't want to replace the `$_.GetEnumerator()` call with lots of `$_.Item("property")` calls and it doesn't feel like I should have to.  Any ideas?

Comment: A down vote?  With no explanation?  The question is clear and even provides some useful information.  Why downvote it?  Is there something wrong with the question?

Comment: Pipe the output (before attempt Fort-Table or Select) to Get-Member and see if you are getting objects with properties you are expecting e.g. `$profiles | get-member` and `$profiles | %{$_.GetEnumerator()} | get-member`.

Answer (score 3):

I've further developed the code so that it now accepts a comma delimited list of properties and writes them to a delimited file.

```
# Outputs a delimited file with specified user profile properties for each user in Sharepoint

# Create array of desired properties
$arProperties = 'UserName','FirstName','LastName','Title','WorkEmail','WorkPhone','Manager','AlternateContact','RoleDescription','PictureURL';
# Specify output file
$outfile = 'UserProfiles.csv';
#Specify delimiter character (i.e. not one that might appear in your user profile data)
$delim = '^';
# Specify Shared Service Provider that contains the user profiles.
$SSP = "SharedServices";

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server")
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles")

# Function:          Get-UserProfiles
# Description:       return a UserProfileManager object containing all user profiles
# Parameters:        SSPName          SSPName    
#
Function global:Get-UserProfiles($SSPName)
{
 $ServerContext = [Microsoft.Office.Server.ServerContext]::GetContext($SSPName);
 $UPManager = new-object Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.UserProfileManager($ServerContext);
 return $UPManager.GetEnumerator();
}
$profiles = Get-UserProfiles($SSP);

#Initialise Output file with headings
$header = [string]::join($delim,$arProperties);
Write-Output $header | Out-File $outfile

#Output the specified properties for each
$profiles | ForEach-Object {
 foreach($p in $arProperties){
  # Get the property name and add it to a new array, which will be used to construct the result string
  $arProfileProps += $_.Item($p);
 }  
 $results = [string]::join($delim,$arProfileProps);
 # Get rid of any newlines that may be in there.
 $CleanResults = $results.Replace("`n",'');
 Write-Output $CleanResults
 Remove-Variable -Name arProfileProps
} | Out-File -Append $outfile
```

This gets me a bit closer.  I'd still really like a script that iterates through all the profile properties and puts them into a CSV or XML file more gracefully.  This will do for now.